# How to add a space if 2 conditions are met from a wall of text file?

Tags: python, notepad++, addition, letter-spacing

I have a .txt file that has stock tickers such as $AAPL, but the issue is that these tickers are stuck to other words such as "$AAPL24H" but instead I want it to be "$APPL 24H" so essentially I want python or some sort of text editor to go ahead and look at a .txt file > every time it sees the symbol "$" > it should move 4 letters > and then enter space

So that $APPL24H > turns into $AAPL 24H if that makes sense.

I have 0 programming but I was hoping you guys can hook me up with a YouTube video that would help me out here? Thanks!

Comment: No coding is required. You just need to use replace with Regular Expressions in Notepad++.

Comment: I am not sure what to put in the "find what" section and what to put in the "replace with" maybe you can tell me? If not is their a source you can point me to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Notepad++.

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `\$....`
- Replace with: `$0`    # there is a space after `$0`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
\$          # $ sign, have to be escaped as it has special meaning in regex
....        # 4 any character but newline
```

**Replacement:**

```
$0          # the whole match followed by a space
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]